aws lambda connect to ssl-enabled postgresql RDS
I need use lambda function to interact with RDS. One of our postgresql db cluster has ssl enabled, so when using psycopg2-binary to make connection, it failed and googled/SO showed I have to use package supporting SSL. I found  [From this repo ] (https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2) and here special python 3.9 version. Based on the readme of the repos, I create a test lambda function with hard-coded database credentials, and tested but failed
[lambda test run output and the uploaded file structure] can be seen here (https://i.sstatic.net/cWpWm9Eg.png). The file structure is like this repo readme indicated.
so the import psycopy2 package worked, but still does not make connection.
here is my lambda function code:
import json
import sys,os
import logging
import psycopg2

user_name = "tuser"
password = "crypxxx"
db_host =  "dummdb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
db_name = "dbcluster"
port_num = "5432"
sslmode = 'require'
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

try:
    logger.info("try to make a connection...")
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=db_host, user=user_name, password=password, database=db_name, port=port_num, sslmode=sslmode)
    logger.info("database is connected.")
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to postgresqldb instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit(1)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }

Any help on this will be appreciated.
I updated the configure to set timeout from 3 seconds to 15 seconds. and invoked the tests.
Initially my zip package contains _psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so but without _psycopg.so, it failed import psycopg2. Once I renamed it and rezipped and uploaded. but testing did not make a connection.
running environment is python3.9.
In an aws EC2 terminal, I could use psql without passing ssl param, it connects

Is your RDS endpoint public or private? Usually it should be private, so make sure that your Lambda function is connected to a VPC that has connectivity over the RDS endpoint. You can configure Lambda-RDS connectivity automatically from the RDS console, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/lambda-rds-connect.html#lambda-rds-connect-connecting

Why do you think psycopg2-binary does not support sslmode=require?

I used  psycopg2-binary as a layer but it did not work. Therefore I tried to use the packages from  https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2

@andresm53 RDS is in private. I tried to use RDS proxy, then proxy works when calling psycopy2.connect() but open and execute cursor threw SSL connection closed like error
